# Add and remove function onclick with js

Tags: javascript, gsap

So I want to add a function that when I click a div it moves, but when I click something else it moves back to its original position, I want to use gsap here too. I tried using an if else statement but I didn't know want to put in here(The part where there is two stars):

```js
let btnSide1 = document.querySelector('.button-side-one'),
        btnSide2 = document.querySelector('.button-side-two'),
        btnTop = document.querySelector('.button-top'),
        btnBig = document.querySelector('.button-big');
if (btnSide1 = **active**) {
  gsap.to(btnSide1, .5, { x: 3 })
} else {
  gsap.to(btnSide1, .5, { x: 0 }) 
}
```

here is the codepen link for this: https://codepen.io/sowg/pen/GRvQxpN

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out I used toggle class list for this,

Here is how it works:

```js
// Variables

btnSide1.onclick = function () {
    btnSide1.classList.toggle("activex1");
};
```

```css
.activex1 { left: 30vmin !important }
```

So when I click on the div it moves position

Comment: This might not be enough information for future readers with the same problem to get help from your question. Can you add some more details, to give this Q&A lasting value?

Comment: @joanis I edited it and added what I know I hope it fine

Comment: @l2aelba It obviously answers the question as it's the solution for the OP.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Look at revisions

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

```
if (btnSide1 === active)
```

Comment: I put it right it the code, but it shows that active is not defined, its at the end of the code in comments because it was interfering with the other functions